# My logi mouse keeps jumping (working not smoothly)

Tags: mouse, bluetooth, logitech

I was working like everyday and i use logi mx master s2 mouse, it was perfect, i'm connecting it through bluetooth.
today i rebooted my system to open windows, as my laptop has two different os on two different SSD, when i returned back to ubuntu i noticed that my mouse is not working as usual it keeps jumping. i opened windows and it's working perfect. the problem is just in ubuntu, so i tried another bluetooth mouse and it works perfect. the problem only with my logi mx master s2 mouse, i have tried to remove all bluetooth files and reinstall bluez but i got same result, also i tried to update my system  but i got no result.
note that the mouse buttons are not laggy only the movement

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed this issue with MX Anywhere 2 and MX Ergo on all linux connections in the past year. They both (and yours) are Bluetooth LE devices. Could you check your 2nd mouse if it's also LE (low-energy) device? I guess there's a too aggressive power saving "feature".
I see questions of 20Hz report rate for BT mice. And doing a human benchmarking, I have 180-240ms with a wired mouse and 260-320ms with the MXA2. So clicks are also affected.

Just tried to play with hcditool, and did the following:

sudo hcitool con

sudo hcitool lecup --handle=mouse_handle_from_previous_command --latency=1 --min=6 --max=8

Unfortunately this is temporary and unknown how it affects battery, but at least it's workable. I still can't make sub-260ms on humanbenchmarking.org, but at least I'm consistently under 300.

Comment: Drain battery for what ? for my the os or for the mouse ?

Comment: I would say both, but more noticeable for mouse (as in 1-2 weeks vs 1 month).